# Redirect all to index.php using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am writing a simple PHP-based MVC-ish framework. I want this framework to be able to be installed in any directory.

My PHP script grabs the request uri and breaks it off into segments. It makes segment 1 the controller and segment 2 the action. This goes all fine  when I do this:

```
http://www.example.com/mvc/module/test/
```

It will go to the specific module controller and method. Now I have a default controller,  the home controller, which is in folder home.

Now when I access this folder directly  `http://www.example.com/mvc/home/`
It will display a `403 forbidden` , because this folder does exist, instead it should also go back to  `http://www.example.com/mvc/index.php`

If I would have installed the framework in a different folder, lets say folder framework it has to redirect back to `http://www.example.com/framework/index.php`

I would like to redirect every folder and php file back to the index.php, leaving everything else the way it is.

My first problem I encountered was it never redirects to the right folder, always to the domain root folder.

This is what I tried :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question correctly: you want to redirect every request to the _root_ `index.php` or you want to redirect every request made to _that specific folder's_ `index.php`?

Comment: To the folder the htaccess file is in, the framework root directory. In my example back to the mvc directory

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Your rewrite rule looks almost ok.

First make sure that your `.htaccess` file is in your document root (the same place as `index.php`) or it'll only affect the sub-folder it's in (and any sub-folders within that - recursively).

Next make a slight change to your rule so it looks something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

At the moment you're just matching on `.` which is **one** instance of any character, you need at least `.*` to match any number of instances of any character.

The `$_GET['path']` variable will contain the fake directory structure, so `/mvc/module/test` for instance, which you can then use in index.php to determine the *Controller* and actions you want to perform.

If you want the whole shebang installed in a sub-directory, such as `/mvc/` or `/framework/` the least complicated way to do it is to change the rewrite rule slightly to take that into account.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mvc/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

And ensure that your `index.php` is in that folder whilst the `.htaccess` file is in the document root.

**Alternative to `$_GET['path']`** (updated Feb '18 and Jan '19)

It's not actually necessary (nor even common now) to set the *path* as a `$_GET` variable, many frameworks will rely on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to retrieve the same information - normally to determine which *Controller* to use - but the principle is exactly the same.

This does simplify the `RewriteRule` slightly as you don't need to create the *path* parameter (which means the OP's original `RewriteRule` **will** now work):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

**However**, the rule about installing in a sub-directory still applies, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /mvc/index.php [L,QSA]
```

---

**The flags:**

`NC` = No Case (not case sensitive, not really necessary since there are no characters in the pattern)

`L` = Last (it'll stop rewriting at after this Rewrite so make sure it's the last thing in your list of rewrites)

`QSA` = Query String Append, just in case you've got something like `?like=penguins` on the end which you want to keep and pass to index.php.

Comment: thanks, you save my day, i hosting flutter application btw, and need to direct url access

Comment: In order to retrieve the path relative to the location of index.php, you could use the following: `strtok(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))), '?')`. This also strips the query string at the end (if there is one).

Answer (score 50):

To redirect everything that doesnt exist  to `index.php` , you can also use the **`FallBackResource`** directive

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

It works same as the `ErrorDocument` , when you request a non-existent path or file on the server, the directive silently forwords the request  to `index.php` .

If you want to redirect everything (`including existant files or folders` ) to `index.php` , you can use something like the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).+)$ /index.php [L]
```

Note the pattern `^((?!index\.php).+)$`  matches any uri except `index.php` we have excluded the destination path to prevent infinite looping error.

Answer (score 29):

There is one "trick" for this *problem* that fits all scenarios, a so obvious solution that you will have to try it to believe it actually works... :)

Here it is...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Basically, you are asking **MOD_REWRITE** to forward to `index.php` the URI request **always when a file exists** AND **always when the requested file doesn't exist**!

When investigating the source code of **MOD-REWRITE** to understand how it works I realized that all its checks always happen after the verification if the referenced file exists or not. Only then the `RegEx` are processed. Even when your URI points to a folder, Apache will enforce the check for the *index files* listed in its configuration file.

Based on that simple discovery, turned obvious a simple file validation would be enough for **all possible calls**, as far as we double-tap the file presence check and route both results to the same end-point, covering 100% of the possibilities.

**IMPORTANT:** Notice there is no "**/**" in `index.php`. By default, **MOD_REWRITE** will use the folder it is set as "base folder" for the forwarding. The beauty of it is that it doesn't necessarily need to be the "root folder" of the site, allowing this solution work for `localhost/` and/or any subfolder you apply it.

Ultimately, some other solutions I tested before (the ones that appeared to be working fine) broke the PHP ability to "require" a file via its relative path, which is a bummer. Be careful.

Some people may say this is an inelegant solution. It may be, actually, but as far as tests, in several scenarios, several servers, several different Apache versions, etc., this solution worked 100% on all cases!

Comment: I just realized it also redirects things like stylesheets to index (-_-).

Answer (score 19):

You can use something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.+$ /index.php [L]
```

This will redirect every query to the root directory's index.php. Note that it will also redirect queries for files that exist, such as images, javascript files or style sheets.

Comment: Interesting why it works with `.+` but produces infinite loop with `.*` ?

Comment: Are you sure that you added the `L` flag? Are you sure that you're not triggering a different rewrite rule?

Comment: yes, it redirects infinitely to index.php

Answer (score 6):

Silly answer but if you can't figure out why its not redirecting check that the following is enabled for the web folder ..

`AllowOverride All`

This will enable you to run htaccess which must be running! (there are alternatives but not on will cause problems https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Answer (score 2):

just in case you were still wondering how to redirect all request either if the directory exists (for core framework folders and files) to the framework index handler, after some error/success attempts just noticed I just needed to change the RewriteCond in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

the above condition states "not found files" and "not found directories", ok, what if just remove "not found" (!-d) line, and ended with something like the below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /framework/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /framework/index.php [L,QSA]
```

It worked for me like a charm

Comment: Finally, an answer that actually answers the question! +1

Answer (score 1):

I just had to face the same kind of issue with my Laravel 7 project, in Debian 10 shared hosting. I have to add `RewriteBase /` to my .htaccess within /public/ directory. So the .htaccess looks a like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing that don't forget to change your `href` in,
`<a href="{the chosen redirected name}"> home</a>`

Example:

`.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^about/$ /about.php
```

PHP file:

```
<a href="about/"> about</a>
```