# How to load a specific page for any given pathname URL

Tags: php, ajax, web, server-side, web-hosting

Let's say I have a web-page called www.mysite.com

How can I make it so whenever a page is loaded like `www.mysite.com/58640` (or any random number) it redirects to `www.mysite.com/myPHPpage.php?id=58640`.

I'm very new to website development so I don't even really know if I asked this question right or what languages to tag in it...

If it helps I use a UNIX server for my web hosting with NetWorkSolutions

Comment: Include [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in your further research.

Comment: Either use a rewrite rule, or a custom 404 handler (my tool of choice, as it has a static apache setup and the routing decision is done in PHP)

Comment: @EugenRieck Custom 404 just feels like such a hack / feature-abuse. But I must say, doing everything in PHP sounds lovely.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647453/get-information-from-custom-url/20647504#20647504

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It's a balance - you win by not having to fiddle with Apache on every change, but you lose by writing something ugly.

Comment: @jeroen Ofcourse you do not really return a 404! You catch the 404 with the custom handler, then return a 200

Comment: @EugenRieck it's getting late...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess file in the main directory of your website.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ myPHPpage.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Brief explanation:  it says to match:

- ^ from start of query/page
- [0-9] match numbers
- + any matches of 1 or more
- $ end of page requested

The parentheses part say to look for that bit and store it. I can then refer to these replacement variables in the new  url. If I had more than one parentheses group then I would use $2, $3 and so on.

If you experience issues with the .htaccess file please refer to [this](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/how-to-use-htaccess/) as permissions can cause problems.

If you needed to capture something else such as alphanumeric characters you'd probably want to explore regex a bit. You can do things such as:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ myPHPpage.php?id=$1 [NC, L]
```

which match anything or get more specific with things like [a-zA-Z0-9], etc..

**Edit:** and @Jonathon has a point. In your php file wherever you handle the $_GET['id'] be sure to sanitize it if used in anything resembling an sql query or mail. Since you are using only numbers that makes it easy:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id']; // cast as integer - any weird strings will give 0
```

Keep in mind that if you are not going to just use numbers then you will have to look for some sanitizing function (which abound on google - search for 'php sanitize') to ensure you don't fall to an sql injection attack.

Comment: And then, for the love of $DEITY don't use `$_GET['id']` in your SQL queries without sanitization.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart when you say sanitization you mean like backslashing and stuff? Also... THANKYOU Yashua!?!??!?! Is that [0-9] thing RegEx btw? What if I want alphanumerics instead of just numerals? Thanks!

Comment: I added the code to my .htaccess and then added a dummy php page title myPHPpage.php and then navigated to www.mysite.com/230498 but I got a 404 error.

Comment: Great, I've updated my answer accordingly and yes that is RegEx