# How to make clean URLs display dirty URLs with .htaccess?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I have a slight problem.
I have a site that uses these formats for viewing certain PHP documents:

```
domainname.com/server.php?id=14
domainname.com/changeserver.php?id=14
domainname.com/customize.php?id=14
```

I would like to make these:

```
domainname.com/server/14
domainname.com/changeserver/14
domainname.com/customize/14
```

I also have various URLs such as `/index.php` and `/login.php` I would like to clean up.
If someone were to type the original URL, such as `/server.php?id=14`, I would like it to redirect to it's clean URL.

If anyone can provide me with a config or help me along the way to making one that can do this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect all to index.php htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess)

Comment: I am asking for something different than just redirecting everything to index. Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent an infinite loop while externally redirecting the ugly url to the clean url and internally rewriting it back to the ugly url, you can use the `THE_REQUEST` trick.

```
#External redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /(server|changeserver|customize)\.php\?id=([^&]+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3? [R,L]
#Change above to [R=301,L] once all rules work as expected

#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^(server|changeserver|customize)/(.*)$ /$1?id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: When I use this, it redirects incorrectly.
/server.php?id=14
Redirects to:
/server/14/ HTTP/1.0?id=14/
Resulting in a 404 error.

Comment: While writing it I seem to have deleted the trailing `\ HTTP` I had behind the first condition. I think that should fix the problem.

Comment: @Samurai8 The HTTP part is gone, but I am still getting domainname.com/server/14?id=14. Tried messing with the code and nothing is working.

Comment: I've added a `?` after the first RewriteRule. This will replace the current query string with this query string, which is empty. Alternativelly, you can use the `QSD` flag (query string discard), like this: `[R,L,QSD]`.

Comment: @Samurai8 I added the revised code, and now it is forwarding to /home/minec288/public_html/server.php?id=14... Beginning to think this may be my system. Can anyone else test this to see if it works?

Comment: Put the `[L]` flag behind all of your rules and add `RewriteBase /` under your `RewriteEngine On` and above any of your other rules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your URLs in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^server/(.*)$ server.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

here is a good guide on URL rewriting

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: With this, if you type in the dirty URL, the dirty URL doesn't go away. If you type in the clean URL, it redirects to /home/minec288/public_html/server.php?id=14, resulting in a 404. Useful article though, but htaccess is still foreign to me.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to use a 301 Redirect of URLS. Here is an example:

Redirect

```
www.example.com/a1/articles.php?id=1&name=abc
```

to

```
www.example.com/article/1/abc
```

For this you have to modify the .htaccess file with the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)&name=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^articles\.php$ /article/%1/%2? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^article/([^-]+)/([^-]+)$ /articles.php?article_id=$1&article_name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: How can I adapt this to what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^server/([A-Za-z0-9-_,()'+]+)?$ server.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^changeserver/([A-Za-z0-9-_,()'+]+)?$ changeserver.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^customize/([A-Za-z0-9-_,()'+]+)?$ customize.php?id=$1
```

Comment: With this, if you type in the dirty URL, the dirty URL doesn't go away. If you type in the clean URL, it redirects to /home/minec288/public_html/server.php?id=14, resulting in a 404.

Answer (score 0):

To adapt to your code. Here is the answer.

Options +FollowSymLinks

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^server\.php$ /server/%1? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^server/([^-]+)$ /server.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Check the Above code. I think this will help you.