# redirect all request to single file and fetch the requested data via htaccess and php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, request, http-status-code-404

I was wondering how can I fetch all requested links via php and .htaccess

Basically I want that all requests (that is not physically existed as files) will be directed to the index.php

and from the index.php I will echo the displayed request.

so iow :

https://puaction.com/nonexistedpage.php

will go to :

https://puaction.com/404.php

and on 404.php

```
<?php

$reqpage = /* fetch from htaccess */

echo 'the page : '.$reqpage.' that you requested is not exists';

?>
```

Comment: Are you writing your app from scratch using pure PHP? If yes, then consider using a framework, even if you're starting your journey with PHP. Almost every framework supports what you want + many many more! Check out `CakePHP` or `CodeIgniter` - they are great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html and [Redirect all to index.php htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess)

:-)