# How I use .htacces Rewrite Engine

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, server

I would like to improve my site by using the page title instead of the php get method.

What do I need to write in `.htacces` if i would convert `/index.php?id=1` to `/page`

Comment: Gonna need more than just mod_rewrite unless you're intending to write a rule for every single page id. `index.php` will need a way to map every *fake* URL to the actual page id, normally with a sort of db lookup table  :see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess/18406686#18406686 for the rewrite part.

Comment: This is better grammar, I formatted the code. "using the page title instead of the php" should be clarified

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^page$ /index.php?id=1 [L]
```

if you want to rewrite every index.php?id=ID_HERE use this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Whilst, technically, this would work every single page would need mapping in the .htaccess file; *page2* => `index.php?id=2` ... *page3* => `index.php?id=3` and so on. It's a little ... inelegant.