# Is it possible to allow only the correct pretty url?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have these pretty urls:

- app/category/overview
- app/category/new
- app/category/edit/4
- app/product/overview
- app/product/new
- app/product/edit/4

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?([0-9]*)$ index.phpcontroller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

Is it possible to define that any other other url goes back to the index?

*p.e.* app/i/am/the/fastest/man/alive ---> app/

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do it always start with `/app`?

Comment: After this code, [redirect everything to the index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess).

Comment: It's the name of my application. localhost/app

Comment: Don't break the web. There's a reason for the 404 response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a new rule for that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?([0-9]*)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I have added ? after index.php

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question

> Is it possible to allow only the correct pretty url?

Sorta, but you have to be more specific on your rules to limit them to that. Take this example.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app

#rewrite rule if starts with /app/product or /app/category
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(product|category)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]*)/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
#else redirect to homepage
RewriteRule . app/ [R=301,L]
```

This will ensure that only URL that are like `http://example.com/app/product/1` will be rewritten and all others like `http://example.com/app/some/other/page` to your home page.