# htaccess redirect when there's no files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a directory with a lot of php files. But now I'm not using them anymore, so I want to redirect to my new url.

When the file exist I'm doing this:

```
RewriteRule client/z_([^/]*) redirect.php [L]
```

But how can I redirect when there's no file?

ie:

the file client/z_123.php exists and it works.

but the file client/z_321 doesn't exist, and I want to show the redirect.php with the same this link.

My question is: How can I make this working when the files doesn't exist?

Comment: Using the option `!-f`

Comment: try it with `ErrorDocument 404     /redirect.php`

Comment: @ChetanAmeta That's a bad example man.

Comment: @ChetanAmeta I already have the ErrorDocument 404 /404.php and I want to keep it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar can you show me an example?

Comment: @BrunoRamalho I am not so good with `.htaccess` but I have got something that I use here... Lemme get you the link...

Comment: @BrunoRamalho http://stackoverflow.com/a/18406686

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `?` regex symbol.

```
RewriteRule client/(_([&/]*))? redirect.php [L]
```