# subdomain htaccess rediect with query string

Tags: regex, .htaccess

i want to redirect my http://subdomain.domain.com to http://subdomain.domain.com/user/index.php?name=subdomain is this possible via htaccess

Comment: Yes. It is possible via htaccess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect all to index.php htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, its possible.

Add the following to your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+)\.example.com
RewriteRule !index\.php http://%{HTTP_HOST}/user/index.php?name=%1 [L,R,NE]
```

The rule above will redirect **foo.example.com** to **foo.example.com/user/index.php?name=foo**