# How do I customize URL in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm new in Yii2 so I have Brands table with their types `('brand', 'author', 'company')` and their slug name so I need the URL like that `www.site.com/{brand_type}/{brand_slug}` without controller name so how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly called pretty URLs. To do achieve that in Yii2 put this in your app config file under `'components'` key

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        // ...
        '<type:\w+>/slug:\w+>' => 'yourcontroller/youraction',
        // ...
    ],
],
```

The result is that when you passed a URL in the format you specified, your controller will `$type` and `$slug` as parameters you can use in your controller which is expected to take the form:

```
class YourcontrollerController extends YourBaseController
{
    ...
    public function actionYouraction($type, $slug)
    {
        // Do whatever you want with these variables
    }
    ...
}
```

Notice that you will need your web server to configure executing your app's `index.php` even if it is not in the URL. For Apache this can be done, for example, using .httaccess [(More details here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

[The Definitive Guide to Yii 2.0](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#using-pretty-urls) has an excellent section about this topic

Comment: As per your answer, we need to add rule for each slug?

Comment: No, the `$slug ` variable as well as the `$type` variable will be available to the controller to do whatever you want

Comment: Thanks for reply. sorry it is confusing for me. If you don't mind can you update your answer with controller method please.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. For example in my table I have multiple brands like Apple, Micorsoft, Google etc. So for each brands I have to create separate methods, Am I correct?

Comment: No, the brand is passed to you, exactly the type and slug in the question

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope I understood. I have to try. anyway thanks :)