# Yii2 url rewrite rule using urlManages for pretty url

Tags: url-rewriting, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to write rule for below url but i am unable to write.

I have tried this but it is wrong

```
'member/find/<SearchForm[city]>/<SearchForm[location]>' => 'member/find'
```

How should i write rule for below url?

> member/find?SearchForm[city]=dilli&SearchForm[location]=chandnichowk

Comment: I am not sure I understand you very well but check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39999558/372580) if it can help

Answer (score 0):

So if "member" here is the name of your controller and "find" is the name of the action you should put something such as:

```
['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => ['member'=> 'member'],
    'extraPatterns' => [
        'GET find/<city>/<location>' => 'search',
    ]
],
```

this should map to 
public function actionFind($city,$location){}