# How to use .htaccess for url rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess

[image]I used .htaccess for url rewrite.These code used.

```
RewriteRule  ^products/([0-9]+)/?$    search.php?srhCat=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

These rule is ok to call php file.But other css,image path is wrong.
How to solve these error.

Comment: Add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: You should describe what you are trying to achieve with this redirect.

Comment: I trying to rewrite these url "http://localhost/superpages/search.php?srhCat=3".

Comment: [RewriteCond](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess/18406686#18406686)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your URL rewrite, the path now changes to

> http://localhost/superpages/products/4

It will then attempt to load your assets on:

> http://localhost/superpages/products/4/js/sample.js
>   http://localhost/superpages/products/4/css/sample.css
>   http://localhost/superpages/products/4/images/sample.jpg

You may check your browser's debug console to check where those assets are being loaded. You may expect to see a 404 error on the said assets.
You may fix this by providing the document root path preceding the asset file.

Answer (score 0):

In your html if you are using relative paths for the js, images, css than their paths should begin with `/`:

```
 <img src="/<path to the image>">
```

If you add the html code of the page or the failed requests for css and image files it would help.