# Home page .htaccess RewriteRule breaks the filters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This might be something simple, but I spent days on it, without results.

My website home page URL by default is 
**https://rezume.am/index.php?controller=pjLoad&action=pjActionJobs**

I want to see **https://rezume.am/** instead.

When I added the following rule in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^()$ index.php?controller=pjLoad&action=pjActionJobs$1
```

Things worked, but filters on the left got broken.

Here is my whole `.htaccess` content:

```
#Redirection code starts
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#Redirection code Ends

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(\d+).html$ index.php?controller=pjLoad&action=pjActionView&id=$2
RewriteOptions inherit

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . //index.php [L]

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^()$ index.php?controller=pjLoad&action=pjActionJobs$1
</IfModule>
```

Could anyone please advise a better rule to skip controllers and actions and see just domain?

Comment: This might provide the answer you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bogdan!
Your linked helped me modify my RewriteRule and get the desired behavior!

Comment: No problem. Glad that I could help