# When sharing on facebook, showing angular brackets in title and decription

Tags: php, angularjs, meta-tags

AngularJS 1 rendering the content fine into title and meta tags, but when I share it with facebook(using url paste in fb post box), it shows angular `{{ }}` [in the popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jYTT.png) .

I use the ans which updated on  stackoverflow. but its not working for me.
i m trying also server side rendering(using htaccess) but its not worked. (as per follow this doc [Click Here](http://www.agiliztech.com/2017/11/07/solving-angularjs-social-share-issue/))

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{ngMeta.title}}" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="{{ngMeta.description}}" />
</head>
```

Comment: Yeah, the facebook crawler is not going to execute your javascript. og metadata needs to be set serverside

Comment: hey @steve   thanks for reply. i m trying og metadata set from server side using htaccess its not wroking. do you have any example of it?

Comment: I'm using phantomjs to generate snapshots, then depending on crawler I serve the snapshots

Comment: please use correct tags. there is no php in your question, and you are not using the graph api or the javascript sdk of facebook. about dynamic og tags with angular: please do some research, this question has been answered a lot of times on stackoverflow already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 - Update Meta tags dynamically for Facebook (Open graph)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262719/angular-4-update-meta-tags-dynamically-for-facebook-open-graph)

Comment: hi @luschn Thanks for ans. i attached link, which i follow for server side rendering. on button click facebook share is work for me well(with dynamic og tag). when i url paste in fb post box. it shows angular {{ }}.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/prerender/prerender/blob/master/README.md ) here solution for prerendering issue.

Comment: Use ng-cloak it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

github.com/prerender/prerender/blob/master/README.md  here solution for prerendering issue