# .htaccess removing index.php from URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

**Need an htaccess/ mod_rewrite assistance to:**

1. Remove index.php from the display URL
2. Redirect the non index.php urls to their respective index.php urls without showing index.php
3. Sometimes there will be url without index.php
4. The url structure has subfolders after domain and folders after index.php with query string. Tried all the answers but not working.

**Example URL:**
 domain.com/index.php/moduleA/modeuleB?var=1&bvar=2
 domain.com/folder/index.php/moduleC/moduleD?var=1&bvar=2
 domain.com/folder/index.php/m1/m2/m3/m4/m5

Comment: `Tried all the answers but not working.` what did you try? which answers? Please show your efforts. What are your example URLS expected to write to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect all to index.php htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess)

Comment: "Remove index.php from the display URL" - Have you already done this in your application?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Doesnt replace the index.php? The url remains the same.

Comment: Check mod_rewrite enable if not install it will work

Comment: Can I also ask what is the point of having the extra two conditions? Can we simply rewrite all index.php?/$1 to $1