# PHP apache2 how to disable directory routing

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have written a simple rest api by PHP 5.6. Here is the skeleton.

project -> api -> index.php, controllers/, models/,

project -> docs -> ...

project -> src -> index.php, some directories

project is the document root directory. When i request with this url:

```
/api/pet/find
```

i want apache to not redirects this url to the 'find' directory. It works on my local system but not working on the test environment(ubuntu + apache2)

With above url i get

> The requested URL /api/pet/find was not found on this server.

Note: src and api are totally different projects but i host them in same domain different paths.
apache config:

> ```
>     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/admin/project
>     DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
>
>     <Directory "/api">
>             DirectoryIndex index.html
>             DirectoryIndex index.php
>            DirectoryIndexRedirect on
>
>     </Directory>
> ```

That is it.

Comment: For this to work you would need to set up `mod_rewrite` rules (either in `.htaccess` file or in `*.conf` in apache config directory)

Comment: Show me your apache settings.

Comment: please check the post, i added apache config to the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect all to index.php htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess)