# Write .htaccess file to redirect url through index.php without the error object not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

this is my  index.php file.

```
<?php

 $url=getCurrentURL();
  $path=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

 $a= str_replace('/', '', $path);
  echo $a;


  function getCurrentURL()
{
    $currentURL = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
    $currentURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];

    if($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80" && $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "443")
    {
        $currentURL .= ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"];
    } 

        $currentURL .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    return $currentURL;
}
?
```

i have virtually hosted this by xampp.My requirement is that i want the url path to be get printed.
for example.i hosted this as www.salary.dev.if i type www.salary.dev/ibm, i want ibm to  get printed.but when i type this i am getting 404 error.Then i got to know that we want to write .htaccess file for this.i dont know how to write.please help me to write the .htaccess file for routing which is not existing.please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect all to index.php htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess)

Comment: no use.any other.

Comment: do u need to handle error document?

Answer (score 0):

Mod rewrite should help.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: What is not working? What error do you see? Is mod_rewrite module installed on your web server? Do your .htaccess file & index.php located in the same directory?

Comment: mod_rewrite module is  enabled. .htaccess file & index.php  are in the same folder.till giving 404 error.

Comment: Strange. Check if your `.htaccess` not `.htaccess.txt` or something else

Comment: it is HTACCESS FILE TYPE ITS SELF.What to do?

Comment: Do you configure your web server properly? Could you reach `index.php` without any URI?

Comment: i reached www.salary.dev/dashboad

Answer (score 0):

try it

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

index.php

```
<?php 
echo $_REQUEST['action'];
?>
```

Comment: <virtualHost *:80> 
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\Marketing site"
ServerName salary.dev
</virtualHost>

Comment: this is my vhost config

Comment: can please tell me what all modification i want to make in vhost.config and host file to run in xampp web server.

Comment: plz give me screenshot

Comment: http://www.salary.dev/Sample/red.here it is printing red.Here Sample is the folder which contains index and .httaccess.i want 
 when i enter http://www.savesalary.dev/red it should return red.Dont want Sample

Comment: `code`<?php
 $string=$_REQUEST['action'];
 $output= explode('/', $string);
echo $output[count($output)-1];
?>

Comment: `<?php
 $string=$_REQUEST['action'];
 $output= explode('/', $string);
echo $output[count($output)-1];
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```