# Redirect in .htaccess doesn't work for url existing

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I create a .htaccess to redirect all url to index.php
It works for url that doesn't exist but for other url (which exists) it doesn't work & I don't know why. Isearch & I tried all configuration but it seems it doest work.

Here my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `RewriteConds` does not allow existing Links and directories to go to `/index.php` . If you want to redirect all incoming requests (existing or non-existing) ,you can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !index.php /index.php [L]
```

Also see this : [Redirect all to index.php htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess)