# HTML Fallback Page

Tags: html

Is there a way I can set a 'fallback' page?

For example, my technique for updating pages on my website is to firstly remove my original **index.php** and then replace it with a seperate **index.html** that reads "We'll be back soon!". This is to explain that all pages are down for maintenance (as I upload updated content).

This means anyone attempting to access my home page will be greeted with the maintenance message. The problem, though: if someone manually types in the URL of the page they are trying to access they would instead be resulted with a "Page not found" error.

Is there a way in which I can direct the user to **index.html** if they are attempting to visit a location that does exist - but just not right now (since I removed it to update content) ...if that makes any sense ;D

Comment: just use `.htaccess` and redirect anything to `index.html`?!

Comment: How does one do that? I am using a free Hosting service (and have never actually played around with a server of my own)

Comment: There's no such thing as "does exist but just not right now".  Something either exists or it doesn't.

Comment: There are thousands of examples for `.htaccess`. Search it by yourself. This question here is obsolete, because this was requested so often. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess

Comment: I should probably read up about this .htaccess you speak of - thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* this is an Apache (or compatible) web server, place an `.htaccess` file in the document root directory (where your index.html usually goes) and put theses lines in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ maintenance.html
```

This makes the web server respond to any and all requests with the maintenance.html file. Obviously, put your "under maintenance" web page there. You'd need to tweak that a bit if you wanted to serve images on that maintenance page, but this should get you going. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20563773/476.

Comment: As an moderator, I would expect you would just add multiple duplicates to the question, instead of a new answer ...