# .htaccess - redirect everything

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to get a landing page to work while I am doing scheduled updates on my site.

So basically all my original files will still exist in the directory including my `index.php` file but I've added another `index1.html`, so whenever I do an update I just want to be able to un-comment a line in my `.htaccess` file and everything will redirect to the landing page.

In my `.htaccess` file I have:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index1.html?path=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This works for me in so far as any file or sub-directory I go to like `example.com/whatever` will redirect but `example.com` will still go to the original `index.php` which is what I want to be updating.

Comment: Probably duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess

Comment: @marcramser hi thanks for your comment. I seen that Q&A earlier but unfortunately it does not solve my issue. It will do the same thing, as in rewrite any file or directory (example.com/whatever) but not the the main page (example.com)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This line did exactly what I wanted:

```
DirectoryIndex index1.html
```