# Refreshin angular build shows 404 Not Found Error on Apache Server

Tags: angular

I am creating ng build --prod in angular 6, and deploying it to the Apache Server.
Build works fine but when iam refreshing the page it shows "Not Found".
Also iam creating .htaccess file in my root folder...

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d  
RewriteRule ^ - [L]


RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: Take a look at that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible reason could be that you are deploying in a sub-directory.

Change this line

```
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^ /subDirectoryName/index.html
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are assuming he is serving the app in a subdirectory, but he never said this.

Comment: I have helped 2 React developers fix 404 issues in past. Both were serving the app in a sub-directory. I'm assuming same with Angular (in this case).

Comment: You shouldn't assume something based on past scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Faheem you assumed right, it really helped me out

Answer (score -2):

You should read the docs explaining how to deploy an Angular app: [Angular deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment).

> Routed apps must fallback to index.html
>
> Angular apps are perfect candidates for serving with a simple static
>   HTML server. You don't need a server-side engine to dynamically
>   compose application pages because Angular does that on the
>   client-side.
>
> If the app uses the Angular router, you must configure the server to
>   return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file
>   that it does not have.
>
> A routed application should support "deep links". A deep link is a URL
>   that specifies a path to a component inside the app. For example,
>   mysite.com/heroes/42 is a deep link to the hero detail page
>   that displays the hero with id: 42.
>
> There is no issue when the user navigates to that URL from within a
>   running client. The Angular router interprets the URL and routes to
>   that page and hero.

There are examples of configuration for several web servers.