# PHP fake url to parse into GET or similar

Tags: php, laravel, rest, url, get

I've worked with laravel earlier this year and I liked the idea of using url to access REST client. I was wondering how I'd be able to redirect from non-existant URL to an existing url and keeping that GET data.

Is it even possible with the current php implementation?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
For example, let's say that I want to allow logged in users download a file. Said file would be downloaded from a following url: `http://example.ex/image.png`
But if I just put my image.png into the root of my webserver, it'd be downloadable by anyone, as it's a direct link. How would I use the same URL, but to supply index.php with `$_GET['url'] = image.png`, so I could give a temporary download link to a user if the user is logged in.

Comment: `Is it even possible with the current php implementation` Of course.  But without any code it will be hard to provide an answer.

Comment: I don't have any code yet, as I'm currently trying to figure out how I'd even start with that. Will edit my question with an example

Comment: To answer your question, yes it is possible.

Comment: Your first step would be to look at [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess/38067042).

Comment: @Ibu I'll do that, thanks. Can you change it into an answer, so I can tag it as answered?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do it like this (in PHP) I don't code Laravel

```
 $arr_url = parse_url('http://example.com/old_location?foo=bar');
 $query = !empty($arr_url['query']) ? '?'.$arr_url['query'] : '';

 header("Location: http://example.com/new_location{$query}");
 exit;
```

OR you can use `$_SERVER`  ( I forget if it includes the `?`)

```
   $query = !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '';
   header("Location: http://example.com/new_location{$query}");
```

Two important things.

- no output before calling `header` not so much as a single space
- call exit after using header.

> from non-existant URL

As I said I don't use Laraval, so I can't speak on to how it handles 404's so you would need to do the redirection in the controller that handles that, which would require some logic to decide to redirect or not.

**UPDATE**

> I want to do it in PHP, but this doesn't really help if my URL ending with image.png isn't a valid php file.

Saying `access REST` implies that it will be a PHP file.  If you just mean finding if a file exists and redirecting then use HTACCESS

```
#if not is a real file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
//redirect
```

How you decide where to redirect is an open question, as this is to broad for me to give a specific answer.

One last thing is your `.png` example. It's possible to use a `.php` file to return image data, with the correct headers.  I once built a site that stored user images in a Zip file and then only displayed images if a user was logged in, by streaming the contents of the file from the ZIP (no temp files).

Everything the server returns is text, the only reason it's seen as an image is because Apache knows that `.png` should have `Content-type: image/jpng` or something like that for the content header.  Something that can be "faked" in PHP.

Comment: I want to do it in PHP, but this doesn't really help if my URL ending with image.png isn't a valid php file.

Comment: `access REST` this implies that it is a PHP file.  If it's not then you can use HTACCESS, but you have to decide what is a valid url

Comment: The only sticking point is deciding where to send it, and catching those 404's and sending them to where that decision can be made.