# React router params - failed page refresh on Apache server

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using `react router 4` on a server which uses `Apache` and have a simple set up for a particular route:

```
<Route path="/:id/list" component={List} />
```

The page get's the id (`this.props.match.params.id`), then does an api call for some of the page content.

When navigating around the app it's fine and works perfectly. However, if the current url is e.g.

```
https://example.com/123/list
```

and I refresh the page, it fails to load. No errors, no content.

I'm using the following in my `.htaccess` files which works perfectly for refreshing non-dynamic pages, but not dynamic

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

**How could I do things differently so it loads dynamic content too on page refresh?**

Page refresh on localhost when developing works as it should.

As suggested by the first answer, I did try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [NC,L,QSA]
```

But no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else having the same issue, I switched to using `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter` and it works as planned. Not ideal as I don't personally like hash symbols in a URL but for now, it's a solution.

```
<HashRouter>
    <App />
</HashRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely the issue is that your apache server doesn't know to serve your app when it gets a request for `/123/list`.  You basically need to set up a wildcard rule to redirect all unknown requests to be handled by your index page (which will do client-side routing).

Here is a relevant question I found: [Redirect all to index.php htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess)

Comment: I already have that in place as you can see from the OP, I have the default routing to index.html set up.

Comment: I have limited experience writing .htaccess files, but based on the question I linked, "you're just matching on `.` which is one instance of any character, you need at least `.*` to match any number of instances of any character."

Comment: Apologies, I should have said, I did try what the other answer suggested but did not change anything - I will update the question

Comment: If that didn't work, I would suggest doing some basic sanity checks on your setup to make sure rewriting is working as intended.  For example, it looks like you may be missing `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: Good shout but as I said, it works perfectly for non dynamic pages so all is working as it should, apart from dynamic pages