# Get an activation key string from URI

Tags: php, parsing, server-side

I have a URL in this format:

```
https://www.example.com/activate/9ajebaidblahdeblahblah2020
```

My setup is /activate/index.php

How can I parse /9ajebaidblahdeblahblah2020 with the index.php file in the /activate folder?

I have tried...

```
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $current_url;

//OR

var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

What I would like to do is (purpose)...

```
$current_url = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
//echo $current_url[2];
```

Thank you ahead of time for any help.

Comment: Use [parse_url()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-parse_url-function/). Hope this works for you

Comment: As in my example, same with parse_url it returns a 404. Assume I don't get to setup the URL (in my database).

Comment: If you are using Apache, you will have to add some .htaccess URL rewriting to it(similar for nginx)

Comment: Yeah, I though so, was hoping there might have been some new magic method since 7.x. Perhaps I will need to go with /activate/index.php/9ajebaidblahdeblahblah2020 at minimum, this I can change in the db.

Comment: I have decided to stay with my original URL, but include index.php because it is never seen except in the email link, the file is just a processor, and then I can explode the result and do like: $authKey = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); echo $authKey[3];
/activate/index.php/9ajebaidblahdeblahblah2020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `.htaccess` file in your `activate` project folder with the below code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?activate/(.+)$ /activate/index.php?val=$1 [NC,L,P]
```

**Demo:** https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=aa64900e-ba78-4f17-9369-326f4384dd47

Later in your `index.php` file, you can just use as:

```
<?php

echo $_GET['val'];
```

Comment: Hey that is a great tool, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have a page named `9ajebaidblahdeblahblah2020` on your server.

You can redirect all URL’s to index.php with htaccess (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html).

See more details here:
[Redirect all to index.php using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-using-htaccess)

Comment: My initial conclusion too, hence I know I need at least /index.php/ in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<php

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$route_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

$segments = array_filter(explode("/", $route_path));

print_r($segments);
```

> You'll get the following Result,

Array(
[1] => activate,
[2] => 9ajebaidblahdeblahblah2020
)