# .htaccess redirecting all routes to a file handling routes

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have little to none experience with .htaccess so I have a few questions in my head I want to clarify. I am attempting to make a website where all traffic redirects to my routing file which handles it. What I have in my mind is something like `https://domain.smt/register` will redirect to `https://domain.smt/router.php?url=register`. Is it possible to do so with the .htacess file or is there a better way of doing so?

There is a problem with this approach though, if I want to add parameters to my url, say `https://domain.smt/register?redirect=page/category/stuff` wouldn't the router file be vulnerable to injection attacks? How should I resolve this if I use this .htaccess approach? Or is this just not going to happen?

I have tried searching it and came across this [Redirect all to index.php using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-using-htaccess) but it still doesn't mention the injection above so is it just me overthinking?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that "url=" part in your router script. Set up .htaccess as explained in the mentioned question and then use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - it already contains the path.

Even easier, put `phpinfo();` to the top of the router script and you'll see what variables are defined in it.

Comment: I tried it out and one thing caught my eye which is: `[QUERY_STRING] => redirect=login/http/req&hello=world`. If I want to use this part in my code how can I sanitise it to prevent injections? Is htmlspecialchars enough?

Comment: To parse thisstring, you can pass it to `parse_str` function - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

As for sanitizing - this is a different question and depends on where you need to use this string. There are number of questions and answers on Stackoverflow about this,