# Clean URL reroute with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-registration-form/) and there is this file structure:

```
└── public
   ├── .htaccess
   └── index.php
└── .htaccess
```

Everything works as expected.

The **root** .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't know much about .htaccess but I suppose this reroutes the URI to `public` directory. So every request goes there.

The .htaccess from **public** directory looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /auth/public
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
</IfModule>
```

Everything above works as expected but I want to enhance it so it works like this:

1. URL `https://www.something.com/anything` stays as is
2. But on the server it is handled like this `https://www.something.com/index.php?q=anything` (technically `https://www.something.com/public/index.php?q=anything`)

Comment: _"The .htaccess from public directory looks like this"_ - why isn't there any actual rewrite in there? What is the purpose of having RewriteConds, that then don't have any RewriteRule following them?

Comment: @CBroe I guess it is an error in the tutorial but doesn't affect the overall result. I'm really not much familiar with the subject.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-using-htaccess

Comment: @CBroe I already found the answer but yours seem to be more elegant. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found out the answer.
I edited the root .htaccess and changed the last line to this: `RewriteRule (.*) public/index.php?s=$1 [L]`

The whole file now looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    #RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/index.php?q=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The rewrite rule which rerouted the URIs to the `public` directory now reroutes the URI to the index's query.