# .htaccess file does not seem to have an effect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
OS: Mac Monterey
Web Server: Mac built-in Apache server (not MAMP)
Server version: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 24 2022 03:08:51
```

Web site structure:

```
~Sites/test
```

In ~/Sites/test/php.index, I have:

```
echo "Hello World!";
```

When I do:

```
localhost/test
```

I see:

```
Hello World!
```

I want everything to go to index.php, no matter what path I enter as part of the url, so I added an ~/Sites/test/.htaccess, with the following in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php[L]
```

When I do:

```
localhost/test
```

I still see:

```
Hello World!
```

But if I do:

```
localhost/test/foo
```

I get:

```
**Not Found**
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

I am following a tutorial, and the .htaccess file is supposed to take me to the index.php file, no matter what path I include in my url.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am guessing it is just a typo, but do you really mean "*In `~/Sites/test/php.index, ...`*?

Comment: Have you [set `AllowOverride`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all) in your main Apache config?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, IMHO, dupe attached is talking about how to rewrite in backend, which OP is already very much aware of it. There are issues of htaccess placement OR could be multi/inner htaccess placements along with path mentioning in Rewriting IMHO, thank you.

Comment: Must be some confusion.  [The dup I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-using-htaccess) does not mention "*rewrite in backend*", assuming that means something about the PHP routing code?  On the contrary, it shows many answers about how to "*Redirect all to index.php using htaccess*", which, AFAICT, is exactly what OP is asking.  It also includes all the key parts of your dup answer.  This seems like a clear duplicate to me.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, yes I went through it again and it looks dupe to me. I had requested anubhava to make it a dupe, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that path till folder/directory `Sites` is your root path, if this is the case then place your .htaccess rules file along with Sites folder(not inside it, along with it), then try following rules.

***Make sure:***

- To use either of rules one at a time only.
- Clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

This considers that your path would be something like: `/root/singh/hddocs/Sites`, `/root/singh/htdocs/.htaccess` and `root/singh/htdocs/Sites/test/index.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^  Sites/test/index.php [QSA,L]
```

---

---

***OR*** try following rules if your root is actually starting from Sites folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^   /Sites/test/index.php [QSA,L]
```