# How to config .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If file in public folder not exist connect to `index.php`.

1. `/localhost/project/` show `index.php`
2. `/localhost/project/wrongpath` show `/public/index.php`
3. `/localhost/project/js/main.js` show `/public/js/main.js`

```
htdocs
| project
| | public
| | | index.php
| | | js
| | | | main.js
| | | image
| | | | def.png
| | | css
| | | | main.css
| | | asset
```

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/38067042/6824121 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect all to index.php using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-using-htaccess)

Comment: I assume with #1 it should be "show public/index.php", essentially the same as #2?

Comment: @Lenny4 The linked question is actually quite a different question (which most of those answers appear to have missed). But this question has a "hidden" subdirectory, which none of the answers in the linked question address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically, you want to implement a front-controller pattern, but the `public` directory is "hidden" from the (visible) URL.

You should use 2 `.htaccess` files. The first in the `/project` subdirectory simply rewrites all requests to the `/project/public` subdirectory. And the second in the `/project/public` subdirectory that implements the front-controller pattern, rewriting requests to `index.php`.

For example, the first `.htaccess` file:

```
# /project/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite all requests to the public subdirectory
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

And the second `.htaccess` file:

```
# /project/public/.htaccess

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# Front-controller pattern
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [END]
```

The presence of the second `.htaccess` file in the `public` subdirectory also acts to prevent a rewrite loop when the first `.htaccess` file rewrites the request to the subdirectory, since mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default.

Note the absence of any `RewriteBase` directive and the use of *relative* URL-paths in the *substitution* string (2nd argument to the `RewriteRule` directive).

The use of the `END` flag on the last rule assumes you are on Apache 2.4.

With the above `.htaccess` files:

1. A request for `/project/` is internally rewritten to `/project/public/` by the first `.htaccess` file. mod_dir then serves the directory index (`index.php`) from that directory.
2. `/project/wrongpath` is rewritten to `/project/public/wrongpath` by the first `.htaccess` file. mod_rewrite then serves `/project/public/index.php` since `wrongpath` does not map to a physical file or directory.
3. `/project/js/main.js` is rewritten to `/project/public/js/main.js` by the first `.htaccess` file. Since this now maps to a physical file, the first *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) fails and no additional rewrite occurs. The file is served directly.